# Saving in HTML/JavaScript causing extreme lag and not working

Tags: javascript

Recently I have been coding a clicker game, and have encountered an issue with my code. The issue is that when the game is saved (there is an autosave function every five minutes), and the game is reloaded, it is supposed to save the amount of coins and upgrades that you have purchased. However, instead, it does not save, and Firefox displays a "This page is slowing down your browser." message to me. I tried using Chrome, but got a page unresponsive message from that.

I am using local storage to store the data to the user's computer. Since no error is thrown to the console, however, I'm not exactly sure what could possibly be happening. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Here is the save.js file:

```
const local = window.localStorage;

class Save {
    constructor () {
        this._last_props = {"total-coins":0,"total-achi":0,"lifeclicks":0,"lifecoins":0,"lifeautoclicks":0};
    }
    __reset_everything () {
        this.populate();
        this.__init_lifetime();
        this.load();
    }
    __init_lifetime () {
        local.setItem("lifeclicks","0");
        local.setItem("lifecoins","0");
        local.setItem("lifeautoclicks","0");
    }
    populate () {
        local.setItem("total-coins","0");
        local.setItem("achievements","");
        local.setItem("bought","");
        local.setItem("pastry-level","0");
        local.setItem("cps","0");
        local.setItem("mcm","1");
    }
    load () {
        player_coins = Number(local.getItem("total-coins"));
        this._last_props["total-coins"] = player_coins;
        cps = Number(local.getItem("cps"));
        this._last_props["cps"] = cps;
        mcm = Number(local.getItem("mcm"));
        this._last_props["mcm"] = mcm;
        lifetimeclicks = Number(local.getItem("lifeclicks"));
        this._last_props["lifeclicks"] = lifetimeclicks;
        lifetimecoins = Number(local.getItem("lifecoins"));
        this._last_props["lifecoins"] = lifetimecoins;
        lifeautoclicks = Number(local.getItem("lifeautoclicks"));
        this._last_props["lifeautoclicks"] = lifeautoclicks;
        const achi_names = local.getItem("achievements").split("|");
        if (achi_names[0].length > 0) {
            achievementManager._load_achi(achi_names);
        }
        this._last_props["total-achi"] = achievementManager._completed_achievements.length;
    }
    save () {
        if (player_coins !== this._last_props["total-coins"]) {
            this._last_props["total-coins"] = player_coins;
            local.setItem("total-coins",player_coins.toString());
        }
        if (lifetimeclicks !== this._last_props["lifeclicks"]) {
            this._last_props["lifeclicks"] = lifetimeclicks;
            local.setItem("lifeclicks",lifetimeclicks.toString());
        }
        if (lifetimecoins !== this._last_props["lifecoins"]) {
            this._last_props["lifecoins"] = lifetimecoins;
            local.setItem("lifecoins",lifetimecoins.toString());
        }
        if (lifeautoclicks !== this._last_props["lifeautoclicks"]) {
            this._last_props["lifeautoclicks"] = lifeautoclicks;
            local.setItem("lifeautoclicks",lifeautoclicks.toString());
        }
        if (cps !== this._last_props["cps"]) {
            this._last_props["cps"] = cps;
            local.setItem("cps",cps.toString());
        }
        if (mcm !== this._last_props["mcm"]) {
            this._last_props["mcm"] = mcm;
            local.setItem("mcm",mcm.toString());
        }
        const al = achievementManager._completed_achievements;
        if (al.length !== this._last_props["total-achi"]) {
            this._last_props["total-achi"] = al.length;
            let cln = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < al.length; i ++) {
                cln.push(al[i][1]);
            }
            local.setItem("achievements",cln.join("|"));
        }
    }
}

const save = new Save();

if (local.getItem("total-coins") === null && false) {
    save.populate();
    save.__init_lifetime();
} else {
    save.load();
}

function savegame () {
    save.save();
    document.getElementById("auto-save-icon").className = "";
    execAfterDelay(function(){document.getElementById("auto-save-icon").className="auto-save-icon-class"});
}

let repeat_save_id = self.setInterval(savegame,600000);

function game_full_reset () {
    switch_tab(0);
    save.__reset_everything();
}
```

Comment: Isn't self an alias for window?

Comment: Also that didn't impact anything :(

Comment: My question is where you define for example ``player_coins`` ?

Comment: In another file.

Comment: When does your program crash ? Is it right at the start or after a delay/some specific action ? It seems like there is an infinite loop or some method is called a lot more often than it should be.

Comment: Basically, it did the save function. I reran and it instantly lagged out the entire computer.

Comment: Didn't ever load either; I had to comment out my entire save file to get it to boot up. This is a small HTML/js game, there should be no issues booting.

Comment: Break on ``if (player_coins !== this._last_props["total-coins"]) {`` What value has ``player_coins`` and the ``this._last_props["total-coins"]``

Comment: Player coins is how much the player coins has in game. Last props is used to figure out which variables have been changed since the last save (for optimization.)

Comment: Can you share the website where you have that game ?

Comment: My first suspect would be the `execAfterDelay` function called with no parameter in the `savegame` function because it may well cause the `save()` method to be called in an infinite loop

Comment: I can share the website but you may have to fork the code

Comment: https://replit.com/@AWonderfulMess/AlfiCoin-Clicker

Comment: Clement you have fixed my issue by leading me to the solution. THANK YOU GOOD SIR :D

Answer (score 0):

Clement Cartier fixed the issue in a comment by pointing me towards the fact that save() was being called in an infinite loop. Thank you!

Comment: No, it was the execAfterDelay.